# DTL - If statement not comparing to be true... don't know why

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a Django project and I have the current models

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic_text

    topic_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Subtopic(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subtopic_text

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    subtopic_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Question(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    subtopic = models.ForeignKey(Subtopic)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField('date modified')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    answer_text = models.TextField()
```

After passing that through my views

```
def index(request):
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    topic_list = Topic.objects.all()
    subtopic_list = Subtopic.objects.all()

    context = {
        'topic_list': topic_list, 
        'subtopic_list': subtopic_list, 
        'question_list': question_list
    }
    return render(request, 'interview/index.html', context)
```

And the following template

```
<ul>
{% for topic in topic_list %}
    <li><a href="/interview/{{ question.id }}/">{{ topic.topic_text}}</a></li>
        {% for subtopic in subtopic_list %}
            {{topic.topic_text}} , {{subtopic.topic}}


**THIS HERE DOES NOT WORK**

{% if subtopic.topic == topic.topic_text %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/interview/{{ question.id }}/">{{ subtopic.subtopic_text}}</a></li>
            <ul>
            {% endif %}




            {% for question in question_list %}
                <li><a href="/interview/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
</ul> 
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However the line in the if statement is not working. When I change the `==` to `!=` it prints (the wrong stuff) so I know it's not my syntax but just the fact they are not equal; however, when I check it with

```
{{topic.topic_text}} , {{subtopic.topic}}

Finance , Finance
Finance , Coding
Finance , Finance
Coding , Finance
Coding , Coding
Coding , Finance
```

My thought is that for DTL it's like Java and that you can't compare strings using the `==` ... but I couldn't find anything unique about string comparisons for DTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're comparing an object to a string.

You can also remove your second foreign key from Question since you already have one on Subtopic that points to Topic.

You would reference it as such:

```
{{Question.Subtopic.Topic.topic_text}}
```

which will give you the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

After doing additional testing, I get the following:

```
{% if topic.topic_text == 'Finance' %}
```

Evaluates to true

```
{% if subtopic.topic == 'Finance' %}
```

Evaluates to false

Now, I'm not 100% sure of the cause but I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that subtopic.topic is actually pointing to the Topic Primary Key (Which is not set to topic_text) and then Django 'hides' it AFTER the comparison with the following function. Maybe? I'm going to make some changes to the model and let you guys know.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.topic_text
```

So apparently, Django does the comparison before the output so what was happening was it was comparing topic.topic_text (A string) to subtopic.topic (An object) and then transforming the object into string based on the def __ str __ function I typed above. I solved it by doing the following

```
{% if subtopic.topic.topic_text == topic.topic_text%}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ifequal for this

{% if subtopic.topic == topic.topic_text %} can be changed to {% ifequal subtopic.topic topic.topic_text %}

Thank should fix your issue https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, that didn't solve it. According the the Django documentation. The ifequal is an older version of '=='. Apparently ifequal is going to be deprecated.